# php foreach loop insert into two tables

Tags: php

I want to insert the array into table.

Each name can have multiple addresses.

`Name` will be in `table1` and all the addresses will be in another `table2` corresponding to the `name`

my array is below:

```
array
(
[name] => Array
        (
            [0] => jack
            [1] => jill
            [2] =>  tom

        )
[address] => Array
        (
           [0] => array
            (

            [0] => jack_aadress1
            [1] => jack_aadress2
            [2] =>  jack_aadress3

        )   
         [1] => array(


            [0] => jill_address1
            [1] => jill_address2
            [2] => jill_address3

        ) 

         [2] => array(


            [0] => tom_address1
            [1] => tom_address2
            [2] => tom_address3

        )       


)
```

Below is the one I tried:

```
foreach($_REQUEST['room_name'] as $key=>$value)
{
  mysql_query("insert into table1(name) values($value)");
  $insert_id = mysql_insert_id();
   foreach($_REQUEST['address'] as $key1=>$value1)
   {
       mysql_query("insert into table2(id,address) values($insert_id,$value1)");

   }
}
```

Comment: Mysql is deprecated please switch to mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not drilling deep enough into the second array. It should be:

```
foreach($_REQUEST['name'] as $key=>$value)
{
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    mysql_query("insert into table1(name) values('$value')");
    foreach($_REQUEST['address'][$key] as $key1=>$value1)
    {
        $value1 = mysql_real_escape_string($value1);
        mysql_query("insert into table2(id,address) values(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$value1')");

    }
}
```

Comment: I've added escaping and proper quoting to the queries. But it would be better if you converted to `mysqli` or `PDO` so you could use parametrized queries instead of variable substitution.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_REQUEST['name'] as $key=>$value)
{
  mysql_query("insert into table1(name) values('$value')");
  $insert_id = mysql_insert_id();
   foreach($_REQUEST['address'][$key] as $key1=>$value1)
   {
       mysql_query("insert into table2(id,address) values($insert_id, '$value1')");

   }
}
```